# Ajax gets correct response but not loading into page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've written the below. Checking the dev tools, I can see that the correct HTML is in the response except it's not loading into the page. No errors appear in the console.

```
$('#manufacturerDropDown').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        data: { id: $('#manufacturerDropDown option:selected').val() },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var modelDropDown = $('#modelDropDown');
            modelDropDown.empty();

            $(modelDropDown).each(function (index, item) {
                modelDropDown.append(
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: item.value,
                        text: item.text
                    }));
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here's the response HTML, I've omitted header and footer:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row pt-3">
            <div class="col border bg-light pt-4">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label text-right" for="ManufacturerId">Manufacturers</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm w-50" id="manufacturerDropDown" value="ManufacturerId" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ManufacturerId field is required." name="ManufacturerId">
                            <option value="217ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">F</option>
                            <option value="227ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Audi</option>
                            <option value="237ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">BMW</option>
                            <option value="247ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Ford</option>
                            <option value="257ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Mazda</option>
                            <option value="267ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Peugeot</option>
                            <option value="277ca128-b8b8-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Mercedes</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ManufacturerId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label text-right" for="ModelId">Models</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm w-50" id="modelDropDown" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ModelId field is required." name="ModelId">
                            <option value="e336de76-90b9-e311-b74d-005056b12c30">Focus</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ModelId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the code for the controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    Guid selectedId = Guid.Parse(id);

    var vm = new HomeViewModel
    {
        Manufacturers = context.ManufacturersTable.OrderBy(x => x.Manufacturer).ToList(),
        Models = context.ModelsTable.OrderBy(x => x.ModelName).Where(x => x.ManufacturerId == selectedId).ToList(),
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the data exemple?

Comment: You're `each()` doesn't make sense.  You are looping over the results of your jQuery lookup, which is an id so only one element, and trying to use data from itself to change itself.  You're never using `data`

Comment: The problem is not your ajax but your jquery when appending the data. Do a minimal version of the code just appending the data to where you want it to go

Comment: Your question is similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343215/adding-items-to-a-select-dropdown-via-jquery-is-not-succeeding

Comment: Look here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537153/how-to-dynamicly-pass-data-to-select-list/56537592#56537592

Answer (score 0):

On the ajax success callback, you are iterating over the dropdown selector. You should iterate over the response data instead:

```
$('#manufacturerDropDown').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Index',
        data: { id: $('#manufacturerDropDown option:selected').val() },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var modelDropDown = $('#modelDropDown');
            modelDropDown.empty();

            data.forEach(function (item) {
                modelDropDown.append(
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: item.value,
                        text: item.text
                    }));
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get forEach is not a function for this, possible because of the data type?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using JavaScript array [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method since I'm assuming that what you get in the response is an array. Is that assumption incorrect? In that case, what do you get from the ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

change for loop to

```
       for (item in data.Models) { /// or data.property in which actual data is 
         modelDropDown.append(
                $('<option>', {
                    value: item.value,
                    text: item.text
                }));
           }
```

**UPDATE**

In controller

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
   {
     Guid selectedId = Guid.Parse(id);

var vm = new HomeViewModel
{
    Manufacturers = context.ManufacturersTable.OrderBy(x => 
     x.Manufacturer).ToList(),
    Models = context.ModelsTable.OrderBy(x => x.ModelName).Where(x => 
    x.ManufacturerId == selectedId).ToList(),
   }

  return vm;
}
```

Comment: This generates about 20k blank options so I'm starting to wonder if there's some other problem somewhere!

Comment: @FullerPrime if you add example of data I might be more helpful

Comment: They're dropdowns populated by SQL tables using List<>s, is that what you mean?

Comment: @FullerPrime instead of alert(data), use console.log(data), see what you get in console and post to question

Comment: Although may be worth mentioning the correct html is there too, it's just not rendering on the page.

Comment: you shouldn't return HTML/view from controller, it should be a list of models, can you post controller code

Comment: @FullerPrime see updated answer for controller and script also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196206/discussion-between-fullerprime-and-satsvelke).

Answer (score 0):

Try some think like this:

```
success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var modelDropDown = $('#modelDropDown');
            var html="";
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                   html+="<option value='"+data[i].value+"'>"+data[i].text+"</option>";
             }
             modelDropDown.html(html);
        }
```